# GraphQL for client api

Tags: javascript, graphql

I'm developing an app which has both a serverand a client api. The client api does not necessarily send data to the server, in most cases it is used only to display or filter data on the client.

I was about to build my client api the usual way, by exposing a select group of functions via `myapp.filterData(...)`or `myapp.addColumn(...)`, etc. etc.

But seeing as I'll be using GraphQL for the server api, I thought it would be nice to have a consistent api for both. I'm not seeing anywhere this has been done. Everything I've seen is client-to-server.

Has anybody used graphql in this way? Or is there a reason not to do what I'm describing? Is this a bad idea?

Comment: what do you mean by client_api

Comment: @aWebDeveloper client api is the ability of a developer to push data directly to the front-end only. You can query the front-end (client) for data or set data on the client, but these changes are not propagated to the server.